# For loop not updating matrix

Tags: matlab

Trying to analyse data, and we think our scripts have stopped working after MATLAB 2014a latest update, as they have worked fine until now. No error messages being outputted but our for loop which fills an empty matrix with our data (from a 'struct' variable in the .mat file called `samples`). However the matrix is returning empty.

We have gone through the scripts and identified that the issue appears to be in the second line of the for loop, as when you extract single column variables instead of `samples` it functions as it should.

```matlab
PupilSize_Condition = NaN(52,2001);

indTrial = 1;
ExtraSample = 25;

indCondition = 1;

for i=1:length(TrialList.Pupil_Condition)
    data = CleaningFuction(Structure(TrialList.Pupil_Condition(i)).samples, ExtraSample);
    S = length(data);
    PupilSize_Condition(i,1:S) = data;
    InterpolatedData_Condition(i) = mean(arrayfun(@(x) x.Blink, Structure(TrialList.Pupil_Condition(i)).samples, 'UniformOutput', true));
end
```

I expect the output to be a matrix `PupilSize_Condition`, of size `[52x2001]` filled with data. Currently the matrix is returning with NaN only.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at ```S = length(data)``` and tell us S value. It's probably a dimension mismatch

Comment: When I do that it says that S = 0

Comment: which makes sense you're still getting ```NaN```; ```PupilSize_Condition(i,1:S)``` just guess what should be the result of ```1:0``` it's an empty array. If you need further help show us the entire code as I see ```CleaningFuction``` is not returning any data

Comment: A good way to test would to make sure that every part of the line where you assign the `data` variable is working correctly. You can try accessing each variable separately.